# PowerShell Move-Item Folder Time Stamp

Tags: powershell

I'm moving some folders and all their content with PowerShell Move-Item, but when I moved the folder its date modified  is the current date not the original. How can I move the folder without changing its last modified date.

Comment: What's provoking the question? That's the standard behavior for a subdirectory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a powershell function that'll do what you're asking... It does absolutely no sanity checking, so caveat emptor...

```
function Move-FileWithTimestamp {
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)][string]$Path,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)][string]$Destination
)

    $origLastAccessTime = ( Get-Item $Path ).LastAccessTime
    $fileName = ( Get-Item $Path ).Name
    Move-Item -Path $Path -Destination $Destination
    $(Get-Item ($Destination+'\'+$fileName)).LastAccessTime = $origLastAccessTime
}
```

Once you've run loaded that, you can do something like:

```
Move-FileWithTimestamp c:\foo.txt c:\newFolder
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way to do this in windows but you can use robocopy. There is an option to copy the modified date attribute.
Run help on robocopy (robocopy /?) and look for /COPY and /COPYALL options.
This only works in Vista and newer Windows versions.